# Displaying item id in sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I created an admin interface using sonatadminbundle, it works fine & can add items & display them, but I also need to display the item id set by default (set as auto-increment) in the admin interface, how can I do that?
[image: admin dahsboard]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that using the __toString() method in the Entity (in your example Category) like:

```
function __toString()
{
    return $this->getId().' - '.$this->getName();
}
```

Comment: an other way is to create your own list template: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/2-0/doc/reference/list_field_definition.html

Comment: `function __toString()
 {
    return $this->getId().' - '.$this->getCategoryName();
 }`
It just showed the id when I click on the category itself, not displaying it as a field in "categories list"

Comment: `    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('categoryName')
   ->addIdentifier('id')
        ;
    }`
That did the work, thanks!

Comment: Another silly question, how can I remove the "Sonata project" link from the dashboard because I couldn't locate the html/php file that contain that link.

Comment: @JihedJaouabi you can overwrite the standard_layout.html.twig -> add in config yml: sonata_admin -> templates -> layout: YourBundle:YourFolder:own_standard_layout.html.twig  in there you can overwrite the footer block

Answer (score 3):

Add id in $listMapper in your Acme/DemoBundle/Admin/somethingAdmin.php file:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('name')
            ->add('id')
        ;
    }
```

Comment: Silly question, how can I remove the "Sonata project" link from the dashboard because I couldn't locate the html/php file that contain that link.

Comment: copy contents of the file /vendor/sonata-project/Sonata/AdminBundle/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig into /app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/views/standard_layout.html.twig. Then find (in copied file) block footer and comment everything inside this block. Clear cache.

Comment: Thanks, but this works better, add `sonata_admin:
    title:      Title
    title_logo: /path/logo.png` to the config.yml file